# show date expired profile in php

Tags: php, date

I have searched for my question but did not find it therefore I am posting.

Actaully I have user profiles in database and I Just want to make search button to show only expired profiles and I have stored the user membership in days as well as in date.

As per date I saved in mysql database in the format of 2013-07-26 and for days I just save the no of days eg: for one month i have saved 30 days.

but the problem is coming only to hide the active results. so kindly solve my problem I am positing my php code.

```
{
    THIS CODE IS WORKING FINE AND PRODUCE THE IF ELSE STATEMENT VERY EXCELLENT
    $your_date = strtotime($row['DATE']);
    $datediff = $now - $your_date;
    $ss=floor($datediff/(60*60*24)) ."";
    $period = $row['PERIOD'];
    {if($ss>$period){$dtfv='<a href="editex.php?edit='.$row['ID'].'">Due Dt:          
    Crossed</a>';}else{$dtfv="ACTIVE";}}
 }
```

BUT MY SQL QUERY I AM NOT SUCCESSFUL

I AM USING THIS QUERY

```
{
    $ss is a function

    $mysql="Select * from c1 where PERIOD=>'$ss'";


}
```

Comment: what is an example value of $ss", and what do you mean by it being a function?

Comment: $ss is holding the information it is difference between the current date and the saved date in the database and then it convert to days with the help of formula.

Comment: select * from c1 where '$cdt'> DATE

Comment: NEVER, EVER DO "60*60*24" (or directly 86400) to get the number of days, unless you are 100% sure the software will run on a system using UTC as timezone. If not, this may cause issues with DST (some days last 23 hours, some 25).

Answer (score 0):

> EDITED

we need to know first ur talbe schema .. I am gussing u have a two column '**period**','**Expiredindays**'

so ur sql statement like this

```
select * from c1 where NOW()< DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL PERIOD DAY);
```

chage `PERIOD` datatype `varchar` to `INT`

Comment: `ID` bigint(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `FATHERNAME` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `FINANCEAMOUNT` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `TOTALAMOUNT` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `PERIOD` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `EXPIRE` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `EXPIREB` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `EXPIREC` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;

Comment: PERIOD varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
EXPIRE varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
EXPIREB varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
EXPIREC varchar(250) NOT NULL,  can u explain this column

Comment: I am not successfull yet kindly help on this please i have coloum PERIOD WHERE i am storing the days eg for one month i store 30 days and i want to show the profile if any profile complete the 30 days as per current date

Comment: first clear about table .. U store days in PERIOD column and how expire date is define .. like date ?

Comment: expire date was not there only period of days is entered there

Comment: but how u decide user is expired or not ,..?